# C# IMongoCollection count every distinct value occurrence

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi I have an attribute that has a list of values (categories)
ie:
doc1.categories=[sport,cinema,etc]
doc2.categories=[gaming,sport,etc]

I want an IMongoCollection function that returns something like this:
sport:2
cinema:1
gaming:1
etc

Edit:

I have found this, is this a good answer?

```
_collection.AsQueryable()
.SelectMany(s => s.Categories)
.GroupBy(s => s)
.Select(g => new { Category = g.Key, Total = g.Count() })
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach yields the expected results. The LINQ query is the equivalent of an $unwind and a $group aggregation pipeline stage. As long as the amount of data is not too big, this is a good approach.

If you experience performance problems or run the query very often in central parts of your application, you could think about preparing the numbers beforehand, e.g. when there are any changes to categories or after an interval instead of running a relatively expensive $group repeatedly.